# Rspec testing a before_create hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test the set_random_token method seen below from my model

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_and_belongs_to_many :users

      validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
      validates :number_of_uses, presence: true, numericality: true
      validates :token, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: /\A[0-9A-F]+\z/i
      before_create :set_random_token

      private

      def set_random_token
        random_hex = SecureRandom.hex(8)
        self.token = random_hex
      end

    end
```

Here is the piece in my invitation_spec

```
it 'verifies that the token is set' do
    @invitation = Invitation.new
    @invitation.save
    expect(@invitation.token).not_to be_empty
end
```

And here is the error I'm getting

```
  2) Invitation verifies that the token is set
     Failure/Error: expect(@invitation.token).not_to be_empty
       expected  to respond to `empty?`
     # ./spec/models/invitation_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm pretty new to Rails, so I apologize if the answer is extremely obvious.

Comment: I suspect you're hitting a validation error before you get as far as saving. Use `save!` instead of `save` to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen times where checking the contents of an attribute/column from a local or instance variable of a record didn't yield the same expected result. The workaround I've used in the past is to query for the record with `.first` and check the column on that.

To ensure you are actually getting the correct record you add a `expect(Table.count).to eq 0` at the beginning.

Give this a try

```
it 'verifies that the token is set' do
  expect(Invitation.count).to eq 0
  Invitation.new().save(validate: false)
  expect(Invitation.count).to eq 1
  expect(Invitation.first.token).not_to be_empty
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Rails Documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark):

> The following methods trigger validations, and will save the object to the database only if the object is valid:
>
> - save

In your test, you are instantiating an empty Invitation but Invitation has a number of validations on it which would make an empty one invalid.

Try this instead:

```
@invitation = Invitation.create({name: 'something unique', number_of_uses: 5})
expect(@invitation.token).not_to be_empty
@invitation.save
```

Comment: what you suggested makes sense, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. it still gives me the same error